# C# - Detecting if the SHIFT key is held when opening a context menu

Tags: c#, keyboard, contextmenu

In my C# application I want to display a context menu, but I want to add special options to the menu if the SHIFT key is being held down when the context menu is opened.

I'm currently using the `GetKeyState` API to check for the SHIFT key.  It works fine on my computer but users with non-English Windows say it doesn't work at all for them.

I also read that in the Win32 API when a context menu is opened there's a flag that indicates in the menu should show `EXTENDEDVERBS`.  In C# the `EventArgs` for the `Opening` event doesn't contain (from what I can tell) a property indicating `EXTENDEDVERBS` or if any modifier keys are pressed.

Here's the code I'm using now inside the "`Opening`" event:

```
// SHIFT KEY is being held down
if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState(0x10) & 0x1000))
{
     _menuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());

     ToolStripMenuItem log = new ToolStripMenuItem("Enable Debug Logging");
     log.Click += new EventHandler(log_Click);
     log.Checked = Settings.Setting.EnableDebugLogging;
     _menuStrip.Items.Add(log);
 }
```

If GetKeyState is the right way of doing it, is my code properly detecting the SHIFT key being pressed?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the [ModifierKeys static property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9byw5s2d(v=vs.110).aspx) on control to determine if the shift key is being held.

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift ) { 
  ...
}
```

This is a flag style enum though so depending on your situation you may want to do more rigorous testing.

Also note that this will check to see if the Shift key is held at the moment you check the value.  Not the moment when the menu open was initiated.  That may not be a significant difference for your application but it's worth noting.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ContextMenu's parent in my code is a UserControl and the ModifierKeys property isn't available either for the UserControl or for the ContextMenu object.

Comment: @Chris - As Jared says it's static.  I updated his answer with a link to msdn

Comment: I didn't notice that.  I was thinking that it was an instance property.  I'll test it out.

Comment: Should rather use:
   Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift)

Answer (score 45):

Use this to detect if the shift key is pressed:

```
if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
```

Comment: By the time I typed this answer, Jared had already posted it. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: Chris is right. The property should be available to you even though you are using a UserControl.

Comment: This checks if the Shift key is pressed, which is what the original question wanted. The other answer checks if ONLY the Shift key is pressed.

Answer (score 19):

It's actually much simpler than any of that

```
            if( Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || 
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl) ||
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) ||
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt) ||
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) ||
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
            {
                /** do something */
            }
```

Just make sure your project references PresentationCore and WindowsBase

Comment: Good, works in WPF too, with `using System.Windows.Input;` at the top

Comment: No use Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices instead

Answer (score 6):

`Keyboard.Modifiers` also works with actual WPF projects!
Also I would recommend it's use over `Keyboard.GetKeyStates` because the latter uses triggering and may not reflect the real key state.

Also be aware that this will trigger ONLY if the <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier key is down and nothing else:

```
if(Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
{ ... }
```

If you just want to detect if the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is down, whether another modifier key is pressed or not, use this one:

```
if((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

In silverlight, at least in latest versions, you must use:

```
if(Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift) {
    ...
}
```