# Test if the Ctrl key is down using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that the user can double click on with the mouse and it will do something. Now I want to be able to know if the user is also holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down as the user double click on the form.

How can I tell if the user is holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973721/c-detecting-if-the-shift-key-is-held-when-opening-a-context-menu This is for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>key. But the concept is the same.

Comment: IMO, It's a messy concept when we have predefined elements in place to aid us here, without resorting to less maintainable 'magic numbers'.

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm sure he was referring to the answers in that thread, which provide exactly what you provided above aside from being a different modifier key.

Comment: @Dan Possibly, but in hindsight this is just comment-worthy, unless he wishes to copypasta from there and duplicate.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Using .NET 4 you can use something as simple as:

```
    private void Control_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ctrl is pressed!");
        }
    }
```

If you're not using .NET 4, then the availability of `Enum.HasFlag` is revoked, but to achieve the same result in previous versions:

```
    private void CustomFormControl_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ctrl is pressed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe, but if that's not possible then my second example still ought to do the trick.

Comment: Enum.HasFlag is about 16 times slower than using the bitwise operation. [stackoverflow.com/questions/7368652](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368652/what-is-it-that-makes-enum-hasflag-so-slow)

Comment: That's a reasonable consideration, but isn't always one.

Answer (score 41):

Just for completeness... `ModifierKeys` is a static property of `Control`, so you can test it even when you are not directly in an event handler:

```
public static bool IsControlDown()
{
    return (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control;
}
```

Comment: This is a *Very* important point to note, in the case you are trying to do this check in code that does not reside directly in a form.

Comment: Why in particular?

Comment: In my case, I'm writing a code-behind dll for a plugin in a third party system. Their entire UI framework for their plugins is all web based though, not Windows controls... so even though my code is in a "form", it doesn't have normal access to the usual Windows Forms properties. As a result I cannot just call ModifierKeys; I need to prefix it with the `Control.` qualifier.

Answer (score 14):

This isn't really an answer to the question at hand, but I needed to do this in a console application and the detail was a little different.

I had to add references to `WindowsBase` and `PresentationFramework`, and at that point I could do:

```
if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
   blah
```

Just adding this here in case someone else is doing something similar.

Answer (score 7):

Even this also

```
 private void Control_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
            MessageBox.Show("with CTRL");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
 if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {}
```

And add references to PresentationCore and WindowsBase

Comment: this works, the other suggestions didnt work, syntax problems.

Comment: This solution is for WPF, not WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

The same soneone said above, but comparing as different than zero, which should be a little faster and use less instructions on most architectures:

```
public static bool IsControlDown()
{
    return (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0;
}
```