# How to hold the Ctrl key down through code

Tags: c#, key, modifier-key

I'm writing a unit test and a certain function will be called deep down in the stack if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control).. I can add a flag or something for the particular case of running a unit test, but it would be too dirty! How can I set ModifierKeys to Ctrl through code? I'm using C#.Net 4.0.

Comment: Try this, you should find answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705428/c-sharp-is-ctrl-key-down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use P/Invoke to call the [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for synthesizing keystrokes.

First declare the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;
public const uint VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
```

Then, in your test, use:

```
// Press the Control key.
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0);

try
{
    // Perform test.
}
finally
{
    // Release the Control key.
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold Down :
Keyboard.PressModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.Control);

Release :
Keyboard.ReleaseModifierKeys(ModifierKeys.Control);