# How to make multiselect listbox only with mouse in C# (Winform)?

Tags: c#, select, listbox

I have `listbox` with some items in it, what I'm looking for this:

always **previous items keep selected** and if i click an *item that isn't selected* it **get selected** too but if it's already selected **it get's unselected**.
I used these code but it doesn't work very well!
here's my code(this one does not work at all):

```
public partial class Options_Form : Form
{
    public Options_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AceMP_Class cl = new AceMP_Class();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(cl.SupportedFiles_stringarray());
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        listBox1.Size = listBox1.PreferredSize;
        listboxitemsState_array = new bool[cl.SupportedFiles_stringarray().Length];
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
        //selecteditemsindex_list.Clear();
    }

    //List<int> selecteditemsindex_list = new List<int>();

    bool[] listboxitemsState_array;

    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listboxitemsState_array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (listboxitemsState_array[i])
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, false);
            }
        }

        //if (listBox1.GetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)))
        if (listboxitemsState_array[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)])
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y), false);
            listboxitemsState_array[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y), true);
            listboxitemsState_array[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)] = true;
        }

    }

    private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < listboxitemsState_array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (listboxitemsState_array[i])
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, false);
            }
        }

        //if (listBox1.GetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)))
        if (listboxitemsState_array[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)])
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y), false);
            listboxitemsState_array[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y), true);
            listboxitemsState_array[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)] = true;
        }

    }

}
```

but this one works but not very well!

```
public partial class Options_Form : Form
{
    public Options_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AceMP_Class cl = new AceMP_Class();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(cl.SupportedFiles_stringarray());
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        listBox1.Size = listBox1.PreferredSize;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
        selecteditemsindex_list.Clear();
    }

    List<int> selecteditemsindex_list = new List<int>();

    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < selecteditemsindex_list.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(selecteditemsindex_list[i], true);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < selecteditemsindex_list.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(selecteditemsindex_list[i], true);
        }
        if (listBox1.GetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)))
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y), false);
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y), true);
            selecteditemsindex_list.Add(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y));
        }
    }

}
```

How can I solve that!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to mention that you achieved this feature with `SelectionMode.MultiExtended` but you need to press `CTRL + Click` or `SHIFT + Click`.

To achieve this **only with mouse**:

**1)** A better solution comes up as when i discuss with @ACE (he come up with idea to use `virtualkey`) is to [press `CTRL` key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839228/3790486) when you make clicks. On `MouseDown` you press `CTRL` and on `MouseUp` release the `CTRL` key.

```
public partial class Options_Form : Form
{
    public Options_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AceMP_Class cl = new AceMP_Class();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(cl.SupportedFiles_stringarray());
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        listBox1.Size = listBox1.PreferredSize;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x02;
    public const uint VK_CONTROL = 0x11;

    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        keybd_event(Convert.ToByte(VK_CONTROL), 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        keybd_event(Convert.ToByte(VK_CONTROL), 0, Convert.ToByte(KEYEVENTF_KEYUP), 0);
    }
}
```

---

**2)** The easiest solution that comes up in my mind (with some drawbacks if you pres click very fast) is to use on `MouseClick` event and to have an array of `bool` that every `index` from that array tells me if selected or not.

```
selecteditemsindex_list[selectedIndex] = !selecteditemsindex_list[selectedIndex];
```

**How it works?**

Take the *current index* and negate (`!`) the value at that index. This way you obtain **select/unselect** feature with mouse.

Because i work only with the *current index* the *others values* from array *remains unmodified* and i can use `SetSelected` for all values from array. This way you can make **multiselect** with mouse.

```
public partial class Options_Form : Form
{
    public Options_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool[] selecteditemsindex_list;

    private void Options_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AceMP_Class cl = new AceMP_Class();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(cl.SupportedFiles_stringarray());
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        listBox1.Size = listBox1.PreferredSize;
        selecteditemsindex_list = new bool[listBox1.Items.Count];
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        selecteditemsindex_list[selectedIndex] = !selecteditemsindex_list[selectedIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i < selecteditemsindex_list.Count(); i++)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, selecteditemsindex_list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'm gonna try it and inform you

Comment: Do you know why someone DownVoted my question!?

Comment: error on second item selecting :(
for this line:
selecteditemsindex_list[selectedIndex] = !selecteditemsindex_list[selectedIndex];

Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: & yeah Actually I want to do exactly Ctrl key operation but just click without holding ctrl key!

Comment: yeah it's initialized! 
I think it would help:
  listBox1.SelectedIndex -1 int
  selectedIndex -1 int

these are the values when error occured

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73861/discussion-between-ace-and-adricadar).

Answer (score 0):

The ListBox control has a property 'SelectionMode'
You can set it to :

1. One
2. MultiSimple
3. MultiExtended

see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) for details