# Detecting Ctrl+Left (mouse button) in MouseDown event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

When I first press down control key (the left one) and then click the left mouse button, why does the following code gets executed. I am modifying existing code and the below code is already there. I guess no one has tried it before, with control key pressed, it has only been used with left-mouse-clicked and it has always worked for that case. But I want a different code executed when the mouse left key is pressed at the same time that the control key is pressed.

```
private void treeList1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TreeList tree = sender as TreeList;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && ModifierKeys == Keys.None && tree.State == TreeListState.Regular)
    {
       //the code that is here gets executed 
       MessageBox.Show("I am here");
    }
}
```

I would highly appreciate any hint or help.

P.S.  I would like to add that in the above case when I inspect e.button value it shows that is equal to Right although I pressed the left mouse button and the Ctrl Key.  That is a mystery to   me.

Dear StackOverflow fellows :I found the problem, since I am using a VM on a MAC I had to disable some Key Mapping on my Virtual Machine preference and now my original code works.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What does ModifierKeys contain on debug?
It is obvious it does not contain Control.

Comment: Is this .net 4.0? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705428/test-if-the-ctrl-key-is-down-using-c-sharp

Comment: The event gets fired as expected and you're certain that the `msgbox` code gets executed?

Comment: @nzic It contains Control

Comment: @retailcoder it is .net4 and the link did not help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I am certain it gets executed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that there was a key mapping between MAC and my Windows Virtual Machine that needed to be disabled.   Thanks for all the help

Comment: Interesting. Have you reversed the condition or trapping `Keys.None` worked?

Comment: Have not tried that yet, I will and I will definitely let you know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

`Keys.None` has a value of 0, making it hard to detect when "no key is pressed" when used alone. This:

```
    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && (ModifierKeys & Keys.None) == Keys.None)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No key was held down.");
        }
    }
```

Will pop a message box whatever the key combination is, as long as the click occurs with the left button.

However, this:

```
    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && (ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Control key was held down.");
        }
    }
```

Will only pop a message box when the `Control` key is held down (and the left mouse button is clicked).

Try reversing your conditions and detect when the `Control` key is pressed when clicking (instead of detecting when *no key is pressed*). That being said I'm having a hard time getting the same code to work with `Keys.ControlKey` or `Keys.LControlKey` for some reason, so isolating the *left control key* needs a little more research.

Comment: I tried your first box of code, it does not work. Can you please edit what is needed after e.  Maybe I am filling the blanks that you have with wrong value.    So, I still dont have any answer.  Still when I click the left mouse button with the ctrl down it executes the code for right mouse click!  I have not tried your second box yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this code (second code-block) - it works! Thank you, @Mat'sMug! :)

Comment: I'm a bit late but since .Net 4.0 (at least) enums have `HasFlag` method for checking if certain bits are set.